# Using InstallUtil.exe and Setting Windows Service Password Containing Spaces

Tags: c#, .net, service, installutil

Our install application prompts for a user name and password and installs a .NET service with this information.  We have a Windows service that is installed using

```
InstallUtil.exe
    /username=auser
    /password=password
    /name=TestService
    MyService.exe
```

This works fine until our customers start using strong passwords containing spaces.  Then this becomes:

```
InstallUtil.exe
    /username=auser
    /password=password
    with
    spaces
    /name=TestService
    MyService.exe
```

This call fails with the following error:

> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\me[snip]\with' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

How can we send a password with spaces to InstallUtil.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running InstallUtil.exe with no parameters, you can see the usage:

> Usage: InstallUtil [/u | /uninstall] [option [...]] assembly [[option
>   [...]] assembly] [...]]

In the example I provided, the code tried to send the password "password with spaces".  This was placed into the command line in a way that made the installer think the password is "password" and the assembly name is "with".  No file named "with" existed.  This caused the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

The answer is to put quotes around the password (and any other parameters to InstallUtil.exe):

```
InstallUtil.exe
    /username="user name with spaces"
    /password="password with spaces"
    /name="Service Name With Spaces"
    "Executable Name With Spaces.exe"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could enclose each parameter in double quotes:

```
installutil.exe "/username=user 1" "/password=pass word"
```

Comment: +1 I tested this, and I was surprised to see that it worked.  I expected the quotes to be required around the data portion only, i.e. `/username="user 1"`.